# Why is the file upload disabled in the Youtube Upload Widget?

Tags: youtube-api

I have just been looking into allowing my users to upload videos to their YouTube accounts directly from my site using the Youtube Upload widget. This widget is like 1000 times easier to deploy that the usual API process.

I have seen that it currently defaults to webcam_only=true but am wondering why? If I change the iframe to webcam_only=false I get the upload button and it all seems to work fine...

Obviously it would be an enourmous time saver for me if I could just use this functionality as opposed to trying to get my head around the whole API 2 way of doing things- plus that method seems to require refreshing the page which is no good for my app.

Any updates on why this is disabled and when it may be enabled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

webcam_only is set to true by default if the api creates the api.  You can create the iframe element yourself as detailed in the "Loading an upload widget" of the developer docs.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget

```
<iframe id="widget" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="https://www.youtube.com/upload_embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
  widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
  });
</script>
```

Or

```
<div id="widget"></div>
widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
  webcamOnly: true;
});
```

Comment: Actually it does seem to be true by default, but what I want is for people to be able to choose whether to create a new video (by web cam) or upload an existing one. By loading the iframe with webcam_only=false I get the button that allows the user to upload a video. This is just fantastic. To be able to allow users both possibilities is exactly what I need.

Comment: As a side note, if the user is not logged in to google, the popup window for them to log in is peachy, but then if they do not have a YouTube channel set up or they have not decided how they want their name to show using the new YouTube name settings the dialog overlays for those are outside of the of the popup. The only way the user can see those options is to make the popup dialog box full screen- which they won't know to do....

Comment: So the code's kinda weird.  If you create a iframe and construct it with the api then it defaults to webcam_only=false.  But if you create div and call the api then it's true.  You can also add webcamOnly to the constructor args.  I've updated my answer to demonstrate the ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the option to upload videos using the YouTube Upload Direct widget has been removed as of August 2012. Although you can force add the upload button you get the button, but nothing happens with it.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget#Revision_History

> August 22, 2012 This update contains the following changes:
>       The webcamOnly property has been removed from the list of widget options that you can specify in the constructor for the upload widget.
>   Previously, this property was documented as having a default value of
>   false, which would mean that the widget would also display a button
>   for uploading an existing video file. However, the option to upload an
>   existing file is not currently supported, so the widget always only
>   displays an option to record and upload a webcam video.

Here is an example of the button with no action: http://sandboxsite.us/youtubetest.php

This is using:

```
<iframe id="widget" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="https://www.youtube.com/upload_embed?webcam_only=false" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
  widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
  });
</script>
```

If anyone figures out how to add the button AND make the uploads work, I'd surely buy them a beer!